# How can I resolve tsx file in Angular 2 / Angular - Cli

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have a .tsx file and import it in a ts file via

```
import {ReactChildComponentView} from "./MessageBox";
```

but when I run ng serve it throws an error

```
    ERROR in ./src/app/react/wrapper.component.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './MessageBox' in '.../src/app/react'
```

In Chrome console I can see the following Error

```
using description file: .../package.json (relative path: ./src/app/react/MessageBox)
  as directory
    .../src/app/react/MessageBox doesn't exist
  no extension
    .../src/app/react/MessageBox doesn't exist
  .ts
    .../src/app/react/MessageBox.ts doesn't exist
  .js
    .../src/app/react/MessageBox.js doesn't exist
```

it seems like angular doesn't look for .tsx files. How can I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to make sure you have configured **webpack** to look for files with **.tsx** extension by adding `.tsx` in `resolve.extensions` in your webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [
        '.js',
        '.ts',
        '.tsx'
    ]
}
```

Then you need to have typescript loader configured to look for .tsx files by setting `test: /\.tsx$/` for `ts` loader in `module.loaders` in webpack config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|typings/,
        loaders: [
          'ts'
        ]
      },
    // More loaders
   ]
}
```

Also you can find more info about webpack and react integration at [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html)

Comment: I had to make some changes in Webpack 5.5.1:

Under the module.rules node I modified an existing loader and had it use the `@ngtools/webpack` loader that ts uses:

    {
      "test": /\.tsx?$/,
       "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
    },

Additionally, you might need to modify your tsconfig.json to include `    "jsx" : "react"` under the `compilerOptions`

Comment: It's giving me an error saying 'Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.'