# How can I tweak angular config to support tsx imports?

Tags: angular, reactjs, webpack, jsx, tsx

I tried to use tsx (for including a react plugin) .

Getting `Error An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension`
while taking production builds .

**Everything works great if aot and buildOptimizer is turned off .**

Anyway way I can modify the angular config to make this work ? Any help would be much appreciated .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This([How can I resolve tsx file in Angular 2 / Angular - Cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796335/how-can-i-resolve-tsx-file-in-angular-2-angular-cli)) link would be helpful to resolve the .tsx extenstion.

If your Angular project is greater than 6 then you need to create custom webpack config and provide your configurations.